# An algorithm that sorts a list of values into a minimum amount of groups, under condition that the sum of values within each group does not exceed N

Tags: python, optimization

The list of values:
**a = [1,4,3,5,7,9,5,4,5,6,3,2,1,9,4,3,6,4,3,4,6,7]**

Group the values so that the the sum of the values in each group does not exceed 10. The aim is to group the values in such a way to have the minimum amount of groups.

In example:
**Group 1 = [1,9]
Group 2 = [2,3,5]**
etc.

I am looking for an algorithm to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated, even if it is just setting me on track with what this type of problem is called.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have
to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain the specific problem
with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Goal:

Minimize number of subsets. This can be done by ensuring each subset is as "full" as possible before proceeding to build the next subset.

Method:

1. Start each subset with the largest available number
2. Add the next largest available number to the subset whereby the total sum of the subset is less than a given amount.
3. Continue step 2 until the subset can no longer expand
4. Begin a new subset

**Code:**

```
def group_by_sum(group_li, total_li, max_sum):
    '''append largest value in "total_li" to group list without exceeding "max_sum"'''
    for index, value in enumerate(total_li):
        if sum(group_li) + value <= max_sum:
            return(index, value)

def main(a, max_sum):
    total_li = a[:] # copy "a"
    total_li.sort() # sort in ascending order
    total_li = total_li[::-1] # reverse order
    group_li2 = [] # output
    while len(total_li) > 0:
        group_li = [total_li[0]]
        total_li = total_li[1:]
        while len(total_li) > 0 and sum(group_li) + min(total_li) <= max_sum:
            index, value = group_by_sum(group_li, total_li, max_sum)
            group_li.append(value) # append value to group
            total_li = total_li[:index] + total_li[index+1:] # remove value from "total_li"
        group_li2.append(group_li)
    return(group_li2)


a = [1,4,3,5,7,9,5,4,5,6,3,2,1,9,4,3,6,4,3,4,6,7]
group_li2 = main(a, 10)
print(group_li2)
print("Minimum number of groups:", len(group_li2))
```

**Output:**

```
[[9, 1], [9, 1], [7, 3], [7, 3], [6, 4], [6, 4], [6, 4], [5, 5], [5, 4], [4, 3, 3], [2]]
Minimum number of groups: 11
```

Answer (score 0):

One valid approach could be:

1. sort `a` in ascending order
2. define a function that forms a group matching the requirements, by appending values from the sorted `a` in a *greedy* fashion.
   This is basically where the optimization comes from, as it's clear that **the more the numbers used to form the group, the less the number of groups**.
3. use this function to form the groups as long as the main list is not empty.

---

```
#1
a.sort()

#2
def group(l):
    _sum = l.pop(0)
    group = [_sum]
    while l and _sum + l[0] <= 10:
        group.append(l.pop(0))
        _sum += group[-1]
    return group

#3
groups = []
while a:
    groups.append(group(a))

print(groups)
# output:
[[1, 1, 2, 3, 3], [3, 3, 4], [4, 4], [4, 4], [5, 5], [5], [6], [6], [6], [7], [7], [9], [9]]
```